# Excel VBA - Find minimum value for each row based on selected columns and highlight the lowest value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to seek some help on the problem that I'm facing. I'm trying to highlight the lowest value in the sheet for each row based on selected columns, i.e. iot1, iot2, iot3.

If you see the before and after image below, **I would like to have the code that works to highlight the lowest (minimum) value**. Thank you very much, any assistance is much appreciated!

Before:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Q75.png]

After: 
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately the site does not work like this, you do not come here requesting a code (there are a lot of coders for hire if you want that), **what you should do, is try to solve this yourself first, post your coding efforts here and then we will be willing to help you with your code :)**

Comment: Exactly what "help" do you need?

Answer (score -1):

Well you actually don't need VBA to do something like this. Conditional formatting will work just fine. Highlight the range (you could go to the bottom of the worksheet), the N/A don't matter, and on the Home Tab click conditional formatting > New Rule... > Use a formula to determine which cells to format and in the formula enter the following:

`=IF(B1="",FALSE,MIN(B1:H1)=B1)`

Click Format and select the Fill color you want. So the way this works starts with the cell you first select, B1. If you click and select B1:H4 then select condition formatting you have to use the first row in the formula. It will try to use exact references with $B$1, just hit F4 a couple of times to remove them, so `=MIN(B1:H1)=B1` is where I started. Once that worked I added the `=IF(b1="",FALSE,MIN(B1:H1)=B1) so you can make it go way down and it will not color the blank cells.